# Difference in pronunciation between "won't" and "want"

Tags: differences, pronunciation

Which is the difference in pronunciation between "won't" and "want"?

Comment: Remember there is no single right answer here- it varies regionally. [want](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=want&submit=Submit)   [won't](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=won%27t&submit=Submit)

Comment: want rhymes with font, the 'o' of 'won't' is the same as in woe or go.

Answer (score 4):

The vowels are pronounced differently in these two words.

In American English:

> **won't**:  oʊ (pronounced the same as the letter "O")
>
> > **oʊ**
> >
> > Lips: very rounded and tense.
> >
> > Tongue: a bit tense, moves from mid to high position.
>
> **want**: ɑ (pronounced the same as "o" in "hot") or  ɔ (pronounced the same as "aw" in "saw")
>
> > **ɑ**
> >
> > Lips: Apart, as if you are yawning. Not rounded.
> >
> > Tongue: Relaxed, flat at the floor of the mouth.
> >
> > **ɔ**
> >
> > Lips: Apart, very slightly rounded, oval shaper.
> >
> > Tongue: Slightly tense, down near the floor of the mouth.

while in British English:

> **won't**:  [əʊ](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/pron/sounds/vowel_dip_5.shtml) (pronounced the same as the letter "O")
>
> **want**: [ɒ](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/pron/sounds/vowel_short_4.shtml) (pronounced the same as the "o" in hot)

Note:

British "o" in hot(**ɒ**), has a very different pronunciation compared to the American "o" in hot(**ɑ**).

Comment: There is [also](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/want) an American pronunciation of *want* where it rhymes with *hunt* (ʌ). And despite what the dictionary says, I believe the most American pronunciation I hear most is the one where it rhymes with *font* (but this may just be in the Northeast).